# A quotient group of a metacyclic group is metacyclic?

Tags: group-theory

I can show that a subgroup of a metacyclic group is also metacyclic. But is it true that a quotient group of a metacyclic group is necessarily metacyclic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, actually proving it for quotient should be easier than for subgroups. You have a group $G$ that has a cyclic normal subgroup $K$ such that its quotient $G/K$ is also cyclic. Now take a quotient group $G/N$ of $G$ by a normal subgroup $N$. The image $KN/N$ of $K$ in $G/N$ is clearly also cyclic, as a homomorphic image of the cyclic group $K$. And for the quotient we have
\begin{equation}
(G / N) / (K N / N) \cong G / K N \cong (G /K) / (KN / K),
\end{equation}
which is then also cyclic, as a homomorphic image of the cyclic group $G/K$.

Comment: Great, answer comes quicker than I expected!

Comment: +1 for using correctly the first theorem of homomorphism.

Comment: @BabakSorouh, thanks a bunch, but I thought it was the third one ;-)

Comment: It is nice to know that $G\cong\mathbb Z_m\rtimes\mathbb Z_n$. See [**PRESENTATIONS AND REPRESENTATIONS OF METACYCLICGROUPS**](http://math.northwestern.edu/~visscher/mathematics/presandrepres8-05.pdf) for more information.

Comment: @BabakSorouh, I am not with you, think of the quaternion group of order 8.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Is $Q_8$ metacyclic?

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Depends on how you define metacyclic. If you define $G$ to be metacyclic when both $G'$ and $G/G'$ are cyclic, then $Q_8$ is not metacyclic. If you define $G$ to be metacyclic when it has a normal subgroup $N$ such that $N$ and $G/N$ are cyclic, then $Q_8$ is metacyclic.

Comment: @BabakSorouh, allow me to say that I believe the definition via $G'$ and $G/G'$ cyclic to be way too restrictive - it cuts out $p$-groups, for which there is a considerable literature. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacyclic_group

Comment: @m.k.: That is Ok. What I noted above was according to the presentation of a metacyclic group proposed by Byle, [Beyl](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-040-02/S0002-9939-1973-0325759-7/S0002-9939-1973-0325759-7.pdf). In fact $H=\langle a\rangle$ is a normal and $G/H\cong\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: @Babak: In group theory, for any group property P, like abelian, cyclic, nilpotent, solvable, free, hyperbolic, automatic, sofic, etc. etc., a group is said to be meta-P if it has a normal subgroup $N$ such that both $N$ and $G/N$ have the property P. So we get, for example, meta-abelian, which usually comes out as metabelian. So why do we not here of metasolvable groups very often?